# org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('�' (code 65533 / 0xfffd))

Tags: java, json, jackson, mapper

I have a Json string in the database but while converting in Java object, it gives following error:

> Caused by: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('�' (code 65533 / 0xfffd)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')

Json is : `{"crt":"wrd","name":"7|6A TTTM"}`

In java code I have configured it and have made it private (not static final)

```
objectMapper= new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
```

**Note:** It some time converts that Json string in Object but some time gives above error. Why this unexpected result comes?

Comment: It probably runs into some byte sequence it can't decode correctly, which results in the replacement character. Check the encoding settings.

Comment: I have not given any encoding setting.

Comment: How to set encoding ?

Comment: @Nikhilsoni can you show the code when you creating the input stream? and also, what is the encoding when you created the json?

Comment: @kucing_terbang: code is - objectMapper.writeValueAsString(obj) and configuration is mentioned above

Comment: @Nikhilsoni hmm, ok, but how did you create the `obj` in the first place? I just want to make sure that when you generate the `obj`, you set the encoding to something like UTF-8 or at least the same with the default encoding you use in the platform where you run this code.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer solution: Remove the first occurrence of the extra added BOM text with a method, such as the following, should fix this issue:

```
public String cleanUpJsonBOM(String json) {
      return json.trim().replaceFirst("\ufeff", "");
  }
```

I had a similar issue which I documented in a **[blog post](https://croc.space/a/JSON-BOM-file-import-issue-correction)**. 
Hope this help!

Comment: please post the relevant content from the link

Comment: Done! Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 3):

this worked for me.

```
String formattedString = yourString.trim().replaceAll("\uFFFD", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

Something is producing invalid UTF-8 sequence (or, mismatch of UTF-8 vs a single-byte encoding like ISO-8859-1), and Jackson detects this encoding problem. It has nothing to do with `ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY` setting, as the exception comes from low-level `JsonParser`.

So you need to figure out why the JSON content to parse is corrupt.

Comment: Thank your reply. Main culprit was WildFly server cluster instance where my Application is deployed. It  was unstable. After restart it, parsing is working fine.